# the supremum of a sequence of continuous real functions is bounded in an open interval

Tags: general-topology

let $f_n : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R, n = 1,2,3...$  be a sequence of continuous functions such that for every $x \in \Bbb R$, $sup\{f_n(x) | n \in \Bbb N\} < \infty$.

show that there are $a,b \in \Bbb R$, such that $a \neq b $ and $sup\{f_n(x) | n \in \Bbb N, x \in \Bbb (a,b)\} < \infty$

I couldn't solve this problem, and I would be thankful if some one could present a solution to this problem.

thank you very much.

Comment: Hint: ask Baire.

Comment: Do you mean that the supremum function is a Baire Class - 1 function? because I don't think it is

Comment: No, I mean that if $a, b$ don't exist, it means that some sets are dense.

Comment: Well, I don't follow you. can you be more specific about the dense sets and the use of Baire?

Comment: Ok, I more specifically mean the Baire category theorem.

Comment: Consider $A_{m}=\{x: \sup\{f_{n}(x):n\in\mathbb{N}\}> m\}.$

Comment: I solved it with the Baire category theorem, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Gribouillis if $a,b$ don't exist, the interior of $\{x\in \mathbb R, \sup_n f_n(x)<\infty \}$ is empty, which implies $\{x\in \mathbb R, \sup_n f_n(x)=\infty \}$ is dense in $\mathbb R$. Now I can see that $\{x\in \mathbb R, \sup_n f_n(x)=\infty \}=\cap_m \{x\in \mathbb R, \sup_n f_n(x)>m\}$ and each of the $\{x\in \mathbb R, \sup_n f_n(x)>m\}$ is open. How do you use Baire to conclude ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon If $a, b$ don't exist, each of your open sets $A_m$ is dense. Hence their intersection is dense, but the hypothesis is that the intersection is empty $\longrightarrow$ contradiction.